# How to highlight menu button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to highlight menu button when selecting menu item. if i select menu item then need to apply current class to (`li`).

This is what i have tried.

Here is HTML,

```
  <ul>
     <li class="current"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">SERVICE</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">ABOUTUS</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">PROFILE</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">CONTACTUS</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Here is Jquery,

```
var opener = {
  init:function()  { 
         this.menuselection();
   },
   menuselection:function(){
    $('ul li a').on('click', function (){
        $('ul li').addClass('current');
    });
   }
}
opener.init();
```

Here is CSS,

```
.current a {
  color: #03c9a9;
}
a,
a:active,
a:focus {
  color: #fff;
}
a,
a:hover,
a:active,
a:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9bzc9j2q/)

Answer (score 4):

Use this, small correction in prev comment

```js
 $('ul li a').on('click', function (){
       $('ul li a').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(this)` to get the current element and `closest('li')` to get the `li`

```
var opener = {
  init:function()  { 
         this.menuselection();
   },
   menuselection:function(){
    $('ul li a').on('click', function (){
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('current');
    });
   }
}
```

Otherwise,  `$('ul li')` will add the class to **all** `li` elements

**Update**

> if i select $('ul li') , then apply current class then i need to remove all other current class if applied from other li tags.

Before adding the class to `$(this).closest('li')`, do

```
$('ul li').removeClass('current');
```

Comment: Thanks your advise, if i select $('ul li') , then apply current class then i need to remove all other current class if applied from other li tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this`.

```
 $('ul li a').on('click', function (){
        $(this).addClass('current');
    });
```

> Update
>    To remove all other current class if applied from other li tags

```
$('ul li a').on('click', function (){
    $('ul li').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9bzc9j2q/3/

You need to remove 'current' class from all li's and add the class only to the parent of the clicked item.

```
$('ul li a').on('click', function (){
        $('ul li').removeClass('current');
        $(this).parent().addClass('current');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Make few changes in your script, remove class current from all other `li` tags
and on click of `a` element add the current class to the closest `li`.

```
var opener = { 
  init:function()  {        
         this.menuselection();
   },
   menuselection:function(){

    $('ul li a').on('mouseup', function (){
        $("li.current").removeClass("current");
        $(this).closest("li").addClass('current');
    });
   }    
}
opener.init();
```

And from your CSS, remove the color from your a tags.

**CSS:**

```
.current a {
  color: #03c9a9;
}
a,
a:hover,
a:active,
a:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.li-logo {
  text-align: left;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9bzc9j2q/4/)